# just installed ubuntu server and lamp server, php not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, lamp

im new here and quite nooby, so sorry if i sound dense.
Im trying to install a small internal wiki.

I have inatslled ubuntu server with the default lamp packagaes, but when i put a php file in /var/www it just makes me download the file instead of processing it.

I dont need an elaborate explaination, just a short quick solution

alright thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there was an error during your install, you need to run:

```
aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5
```

and then run

```
sudo a2enmod php4
```

Hope that helps,
RayQuang

Comment: The should probably be "sudo a2enmod php5", although as far as I know libapache2-mod-php5 is enabled on install by default.